# Sharepoint webservice rename a folder

Tags: c#, web-services, sharepoint, sharepoint-webservice

I am trying to use sharepoint webservice to rename a folder. I tried the below code to create a folder which works fine. But I am unable to find the webmethod related to renaming folder. Any help would be highly appreciated.

**Web Service used**
http://myservicelink:100/_vti_bin/Dws.asmx

```
 Dws objDws = new Dws();
            objDws.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

        string strResult = objDws.CreateFolder("MyMainFolders/MyFolder");
        Console.WriteLine(strResult);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no way to do it with web services API. But do you really have reasons to use the [deprecated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj164060.aspx#DeprecatedAPIs) web-services API? (one I may think of is, you need to support SharePoint 2007 and below).

The better SharePoint API is called Share Point Client Object Model (CSOM). Here is a blog article explaining basic folder operations:

[Manage (Create/Delete/Rename) list folders with SP Client Object Model](http://ranaictiu-technicalblog.blogspot.co.at/2010/03/sharepoint-2010-manage.html)